# No rc command on solaris?

Tags: gcc, solaris

I'm trying to compile nmap on solaris, however the rc command is missing,

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/export/home/src/nmap-7.40/libpcap'
rc libpcap.a pcap-dlpi.o fad-glifc.o pcap.o inet.o gencode.o optimize.o nametoaddr.o etherent.o savefile.o sf-pcap.o sf-pcap-ng.o pcap-common.o bpf_image.o bpf_dump.o dlpisubs.o scanner.o grammar.o bpf_filter.o version.o
make[1]: rc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [libpcap.a] Error 127
```

I've tried to look for `rc` or `grc` in `/`, but never found an executable.

Any ideas?

Comment: The tag description says *An "rc" file is a file read at startup of a program. It is also the name of the Plan 9 Shell.* What do *you* mean by `rc`? (I know `ar` but you seem to only mention it in the title).

Comment: @n.m. by rc I mean the error message in the output, aka `rc: Command not found`

Comment: FYI ar is located in `/usr/ccs/bin/ar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rc` is intended to be an argument to `ar`, not a command. However the `$(AR)` make variable that should normally point to `ar` is, for some unknown reason, undefined. Thus this line:

```
$(AR) rc $@ $(OBJ) $(ADDLARCHIVEOBJS)
```

becomes what you are seeing.

You can try to fix this by running `make whatever... AR=ar`, or perhaps by using GNU `make`.